# Uppercase letters in Edit control in WiX

Tags: wix

I'm creating a WiX installer for an application. I have a requirement to make the text in an Edit control uppercase (replace lowercase letters with uppercase as the input is being given).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, you ever solve this problem? Currently would like to implement the same thing.

Comment: @NatalieCarr No, I wasn't able. I believe this is a limitation of the MSIs. AFAIK even products like InstallShield inject their own dialogs if you want to do anything fancy. So your best bet is to create a custom action that will pop a dialog.

Comment: Thanks, the edit controls on my dialog are generated from custom action so I easily was able to change it to capitals. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it without a custom action (CA). The most straightforward approach which comes to my mind is to create an immediate CA, which converts the value of the Edit control Property to UPPERCASE before using it further.

Hope it helps. If there's a simpler way, I would be happy to know it! :)